# Check if custom Recovery has been installed

Tags: android, root, recovery

I am developing a custom Antivirus app, which will need Storage Permission, Root Access and having a custom Recovery like TWRP installed.

For granting Storage Permission, I can easily use `ContextCompat` or `EasyPermissions`. I would rather use `EasyPermissions`, since it is way easier for me.

Well, I searched almost the whole internet to find any library to check for Root Access. I literally found two libraries by Stericson. Now I have the `RootTools` and `RootShell` on my Android Studio Project. I can handle for Root Access. For those two permissions (Storage, Root): I can handle it.

Now, I know that somewhere in `/dev/block` can have the recovery image. But how can I determine, which one is installed? I mean, if my Antivirus App fails to scan and deletes critical files without even noticing it, then Android can say "goodbye". That's why I want to check if a custom Recovery (for example: TWRP) is installed or not, so it can recover deleted files.

Is there any dependency for it to check custom recovery or other way? I would really need it because I can't have all these reports on me saying that I made an app telling about it, that I damaged someone's device and need to pay for example, $200 away. Look, if I get a report saying that my app damaged that `preloader / bootloader` file on someone's device, then I would need to send any motherboard / phone replacement to that one, that got damaged. I would need to ask that person the address to send the replacement. Really, if I get a report coming from telling me that any kind of system or other image got broken, I'm outta here!

Comment: Probably like on my last post about "logo.bin", I won't probably get any answers to this.

Comment: I found [this](https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html), it doesn't have a check command but my plan is to use it and read the output, according to the output my app can know if twrp is installed or not